# Switch to other program and then bring to front again causes .Net MAUI application restart

Tags: android, maui, .net-maui.shell

I have developed .Net MAUI application 7.x. On Adroid, while running application when I switch to another application (move MAUI app to background) and then reactivate my MAUI application (move it to front) causes my application restart and navigate to Login page.

Anyone please guide how to keep application on the same page status instead of restart, when it reactivated?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested without debugger attached? If device OS decides to terminate app, there isn't any built-in mechanism to get back to same page. Its up to you to decide what to keep track of, to save that in app's local storage when app goes to background, and to use that information when app resumes. See [App lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle).

Comment: With the debugger attached, do you get any errors? Or when you check the device log, do you see any error messages? The behavior you describe often occurs either when you don't save state (like Toolmaker Steve) mentioned, or the app silently crashes and then is restarted by the OS when it is being moved to the foreground again.

Comment: You can save the current page in the storage and then go to this page in the App's OnResume() method.